# stringstream won't convert to correct number value

Tags: c++

[SOLVED] See my answer below.

I am trying to use stringstream (named ss) to convert some strings to ints and some to double and such, but the values are all coming out wrong. I have a vector of strings named vec, initialized like this:
[0] = ID # in hex
[1] = phone number
[2] = last name
[3] = first name
[4] = sales number
[5] = percent of sales
Now I go through the vector and put the values into int, string, or double:

```
std::string lname, fname, pnum;
int ID;
double sales, percent;

if(vec.size()!=6) {
    //throw exception
}
else {
    ss<<std::hex<<vec[0];
    ss>>ID;

    pnum = vec[1];
    lname = vec[2];
    fname = vec[3];

    ss<<vec[4];
    ss>>sales;

    ss<<vec[5];
    ss>>percent;
}
```

but the output looks like this for every customer. What are my ints always 1 and my doubles always this weird number?

Customer made: Langler Tyson 1 7667230284 2.12303e-314 2.12201e-314

Comment: Curious as to why you considered a `vector` instead of a `struct` to hold the details? Were you intending to create a `vector<Customer>` where `Customer` is a `struct Customer { int id; long phone_no; string lastname; string firstname; /* rest of the fields*/ };`?

Comment: Well I have a line in the stringstream that looks like this:
5E56,7667230284,Langler,Tyson,31.2147,0.00042117361
So my logic was, the easiest way to split this up and count the items is ( I need to throw an exception if there isn't 6 items):
while(getline(ss,string,',')) { vec.push_back(string); }
I have a vector<Customer> somewhere else, but in this context I am created a Customer and returning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to introduce a separator between the numbers to be ablew to extract them out:

```
ss << vec[0] << " ";
ss >> ID;
ss << vec[4] << " ";
ss >> sales;
ss << vec[5] << " ";
ss >> percent;
```

Besides this, you need to revert back to the original decimal format after extracting the ID:

```
ss << hex;
ss << vec[0] << " ";
ss >> ID;
ss << dec;
```

Also, because you use the same `ss` stream to extract the vector elements, the state of the stream is in error after the last vector element is extracted.  You need to clear the error state before further insertion/extraction.  Using a new stream will solve the problem as well:

```
ss = stringstream();
ss << hex;
ss << vec[0] << " ";
ss >> ID;
ss << dec;
ss << vec[4] << " ";
ss >> sales;
ss << vec[5] << " ";
ss >> percent;
```

Comment: @wright8191 - It does for me: http://ideone.com/1MUgC.  If you comment out the `ss<<" ";` parts you get 0 (as I have initialized the values to 0) indicating extraction failure.

Comment: I initialized to 0 like you did, and did this: http://i.imgur.com/QTZKu.png. And it prints out 5E56 and then 0, and ID gets the value 0. Does it have something to do with the vector?

Comment: @wright8191 - what is the type of `ss`?  How do you initialize it?  Do you insert anything before `vec[0]`? What is the value of vec[0]?

Comment: @wright8191 - OK, I think I got it: you need to use `ss << std::dec;` after the insertion of `vec[0]`: http://ideone.com/9dLCd

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12827/discussion-between-wright8191-and-attila)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. Here is a screenshot of my whole method: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBC8h.png I think that since I used ss to load the vector, reusing it to get the values caused problems. Everything worked correctly when I added the 2nd stringstream ss2.

Comment: See an explanation of why you needed that in my updated answer